# Convert ruby string to date

Tags: ruby, date

How can I convert the following date in string format to a ruby date: "2014-06-03T14:16:32.222420".

I tried the following but I get the error "invalid date":

Date.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N")

Comment: You have wrong title, it should be like "error while converting..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require "time"
Time.parse "2014-06-03T14:16:32.222420"
# => 2014-06-03 14:16:32 +0900
```